# SEO friendly URLs IS working but homepage doesn't work anymore

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I'd like to use SEO friendly URLs on my website so I wrote the following code to my .htaccess file:

```
# url rewrite query string removal....
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1
# url rewrite query string removal....
```

OR the code below (NOT used at the same moment and both seems to do the same for me)

```
# url rewrite query string removal..
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1
# TEST 
# url rewrite query string removal..
```

Both work just fine for all pages except 1 page. My homepage is not working if I try to visit domain for example www.example.com is not working but www.example.com/home is working.

My question is: How can I have SEO friendly homepage if:

The original url is http://www.example.com/index.php?pagina=home AND if I use the .htaccess code it will be http://www.example.com/home but as I do not like www.example.com/home as my homepage, I'd like to rewrite the homepage to www.example.com and all others should be at www.example.com/filename where filename can be any of the file names that can be found in the /pagina/ folder.

How to set homepage to www.example.com instead of www.example.com/home without any errors and what .htaccess code is best for me?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Code markup is for marking up code, not acronyms, abbreviations, quotes, or any other content you want to draw attention to that is not *code*.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you for setting this straight.

Comment: Thank you for the information on when not to use code tags, I will remember and never use code tags again to get attention to any word or text. I will use code tags for code only, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a redirect for `/home` and keep that rule before current rule.

Have it this way:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1 [L,QSA]
# url rewrite query string removal....
```